# How to get relative time from a UTC date using Luxon?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, luxon

I store my creation dates for posts as DateTime.UtcNow() with my .net core api.

If I use Moment.js it is as simple as :

```
convertedDate(date: Date) {
    return moment.utc(date).fromNow();
}
```

This returns something like 22 hours ago or 19 minutes ago.

I was unable to really find information on how to work with the luxon library.

Any tips?

Comment: are you asking how to use Luxon library  or else?

Comment: Preferably how to implement the same method using Luxon library. @AbuSufian

Comment: in Luxon you have to use 'toRelative()' instead of 'fromNow()'. you can go through this documentation: https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/docs/moment.md

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Luxon doesn't support this behavior because it doesn't have access to internationalized strings. More information/alternatives can be found here.

https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/364

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toRelative()` `luxon` function, it works same way. For example:

```
DateTime.local().minus({ days: 2 }).toRelative() //=> "2 days ago"
```

Answer (score 1):

First include library or install, say like

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.10.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Then use following format to get proper output:

```
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
console.log(DateTime.local().plus({ days: 1 }).toRelative()); // in 23 hours
console.log(DateTime.local().minus({ days: 2 }).toRelative({ unit: "hours" })); //48 hours ago
console.log(DateTime.local().toObject()); // year: 2020 month: 2 day: 25 hour: 0 minute: 4 second: 20 millisecond: 764
console.log(DateTime.local(2014, 7, 13).toSQL({ includeZone: true })); // 2014-07-13 00:00:00.000 Asia/Dhaka
```

Besides, If you want to explore more to learn other methods please read documentation for Luxon.

```
https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html
```